# Cube Translation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't understand why my cube won't to translate in the fineMovimento (endMovement) vector3 position along Z.

Here the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovimentoPorta : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;
    Vector3 fineMovimento = new Vector3(221.04f, -8.98f,329);
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            while (target.position != fineMovimento)
            {
                target.Translate (Vector3.forward*10.0f*Time.deltaTime); //il cubo si doverbbe muovere lungo l'asse Z +
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `while(...)` in `void Update()` for translate (Because Unity hangs when you press <kbd>P</kbd> in play mode).  If you want to move to `fineMovimento` smoothly, one way is to use `Vector3.Lerp()`.

Try this:

```
public Transform target;
Vector3 fineMovimento;
float smoothTime = 0.125f;

void Start()
{
    fineMovimento = target.position; // Initialize
}

void Update () 
{
    target.position = Vector3.Lerp(target.position, fineMovimento, smoothTime);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
    {
        fineMovimento = new Vector3(221.04f, -8.98f,329); // Set end position
    }
}
```

Hope this what you want.

Comment: Really Thank You Man... This works perfectly how I wanted... gg!